# CSS/HTML How to hover over an image and have another one appear in a different spot

Tags: html, css

So I'm not going to apply code because it's just a super quick question that I hope doesn't have a complex answer. What I want to do is have one picture where when I put my mouse on top of it then a bigger version of that picture will appear to the right of the original small picture.

If anyone knows what elements I need to use for this that would help me get on the right track. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant css

```
#picture {width:100px; height: 250px; background-color:#ffffff;}
#picture a.small, #picture a.small:visited { display:block; width:100px; height:100px; text-decoration:none; background:#ffffff; top:0; left:0; border:0;}
#picture a img {border:0;}
#picture a.small:hover {text-decoration:none; background-color:#000000; color:#000000;}
#picture a .large {display:block; position:absolute; width:0; height:0; border:0; top:0; left:0;}
#picture a.small:hover .large {display:block; position:absolute; top: 90px; left:150px; width:200px; height:200px; }
```

And this is the relevant html

```
<div id="picture">
<a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image"><img src="images/jupiter-s.jpg" title="small image" />
<img class="large" src="images/jupiter-l.jpg" title="large image" /></a>
</div>
```

Let's look at the css and html that make the magnification happen.
    #picture a .large {display:block; position:absolute; width:0; height:0; border:0; top:0; left:0;}

You are telling any links within the picture div, with the .large class specified, that they are to display as nothing! Take a look at the code. 0 width, 0 height, 0 border!! Any links with the .large class specified won't be seen UNLESS it’s hovered over AND has the .small and .large classes specified because you have a separate rule for "hover .small .large" which is:

```
#picture a.small :hover .large {display:block; position:absolute; top:-65px; left:150px; width:200px; height:200px;}
```

This tells the element that instead of being 0 x 0 in size it's to be 200 x 200 and voila! You can see the picture! Clever isn’t it!
Magnify an image

As you will see from the html code above your anchor’s class is .small and your image class is .large. So if your link is hovered over then

```
 #menu a.p1:hover .large {display:block; position:absolute; top:-65px; left:150px; width:300px; height:300px;
```

Data shared from: http://www.dreamweaverclub.com/dreamweaver-show-larger-image.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the adjacent selector `+`, which applies css to the element directly after.

```
.small-img:hover + .big-img{
    display:block
}    
.big-img{
    display:none
}
```

The html would be:

```
<img class="small-img">
<img class="big-img">
```